# How do I link a custom voice command to a shortcut?

Tags: shortcuts-app, voice-control

I just upgraded to Monterrey and I'm playing with Shortcuts.  It struck me as useful to trigger shortcuts from custom voice commands (yes, you can create your own voice commands in Voice Control).  But there doesn't seem to be any direct way of doing it.

How can I easily link these?